# Logging in and downloading content using PHP and CURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to log in to site and then go to one of the pages and retrieve the data. I have a problem with authorization. 
Sample code:

```
$loginUrl = 'https://strona.pl/authorization'; //action from the login form
$loginFields = array('username'=>'mail@mojmail.pl', 'password'=>'haslo'); //login form field names and values
$remotePageUrl = 'https://strona.pl/pdstrona'; //url of the page you want to save  

$login = getUrl($loginUrl, 'post', $loginFields); //login to the site

$remotePage = getUrl($remotePageUrl); //get the remote page

function getUrl($url, $method='', $vars='') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($method == 'post') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
        //jeżeli pojawił się błąd to go wyświetlimy
        if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
        {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $buffer;
        print $status;
}
// wyłącza pokazywanie błędów dla funkcji loadHTML
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom ->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
$dom->loadHTML($remotePage);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
```

As a result of this query I am redirected to the main page (not the sub). What is important, I enter email address into a script in encoded form. Example: email% 40mojmail.pl

edit

Ok - I will add some information . I am a publisher and working with afilo.pl . Daily checking of rates is very tiring, so I wanted to prepare a script that will collect data once a day and informed me of the changes.

Unfortunately I can not retrieve the data.
Sample cookies from my browser :
Set- Cookie: PHPSESSID = jat102p33s0pmfairri1qiih24 ; expires = Thu, 25 -Dec- 2013 9:16:40 p.m. GMT ; path = / ; domain = . Afilo.pl

I modified the code but it still does not work.

```
loginUrl = 'https://opentrack.afilo.pl/logowanie'; //action from the login form
$loginFields = array('loginemail'=>'.......','loginhaslo'=>'........'); 
//login form field names and values
$remotePageUrl = 'https://opentrack.afilo.pl/partner/programy-lista'; //url of the page you want to save  



$login = getUrl($loginUrl, 'post', $loginFields); //login to the site

$remotePage = getUrl($remotePageUrl); //get the remote page

function getUrl($url, $method='', $vars='') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($method == 'post') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    }

    session_start();
    $strCookie = session_name() . '=' . $_COOKIE[ session_name() ] . '; path=/;     domain=.afilo.pl'; 
    session_write_close(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie );
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    //jeÂżeli pojawiÂł siĂŞ bÂłÂąd to go wyĹ“wietlimy
    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
        {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
        }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $buffer;
    print $status;
}
```

Comment: if the site wanted you to access data programmatically they would of provided an API

Comment: sorry :) I made a mistake in the title. I'm trying to simply log in and go to the sub and then download the data. Page does not provide API.  I noticed that my code does not work on pages that use the mail address as a login.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to my question. This code works well.

```
// options
$EMAIL            = 'login';
$PASSWORD         = 'haslo';
$cookie_file_path = "/cookies/cookies.txt";
$LOGINURL         = "https://domainname.com/auth"; 
$agent            = "Nokia-Communicator-WWW-Browser/2.0 (Geos 3.0 Nokia-9000i)";


$ch = curl_init(); 

$headers[] = "Accept: */*";
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL);


$fields = array(); 
$fields['loginemail'] = $EMAIL;
$fields['loginhaslo'] = $PASSWORD;


$POSTFIELDS = http_build_query($fields); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTFIELDS); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);  


$remotePageUrl = 'https://domainname.com/partner/programy-lista';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remotePageUrl); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```